# DRF Serializer manipulating with third party app over REST API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

As a picture is worth a thousand words, let's do it this way. So, I am trying to manipulate with Third party application over the REST CRUD API.

Now, I would like to use Django Rest API routers and all the benefits that it will bring to my app. To use routers I will have to use ViewSets. Instead of models I am using just simple python class since I do not have to store any data (perhaps this is not needed at all?).

The question is, how to create Serializers that will transform complicated json data that is coming from Third party service, transform it and send it to Fronted. But when I change data on Frontend app to propagate changes and update Third party app.

[image]

So far I have this:

urls.py

```
router.register(r'applications', ApplicationViewSet, base_name='application')
```

models.py

```
class Application(object):

    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
```

serializers.py

```
class ApplicationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
    #color = ??? How to transform and serialize dict value to field ?
```

views.py

```
class ApplicationViewSet(ViewSet):

    def create(self, request):
        # I guess that this logic should be handled by serializes as well?. 
        name = request.data.get('name')
        color = request.data.get('color')
        result = third_party_service.create_application(request, name)
        app = Application(**result)
        if color:
            app.color = color
            third_party_service.update_application(request, app)
        return Response(app)

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = third_party_service.get_applications(request)
        serializer = ApplicationSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        app = third_party_service.get_application(request, pk)
        serializer = ApplicationSerializer(instance=app)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

JSON coming from third party app:

```
{
  "name": "Application",
  "attributeCollection": {
    "attributeArray": [
      {
        "name": "color",
        "value": [
          "red",
          "green"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "text",
        "value": [
          "bold"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

JSON that is send to Frontend:

```
{
  "name": "Application",
  "color": ["red", "green"]
}
```

I am not really advanced user of DRF so maybe I am using it on the wrong way. Any suggestion on how to achieve this will be very helpful!

Comment: You could use a serializer here for validation purposes, and maybe a class could help you with the data transform, but you don’t need any kind of model at all here. Just use the JSON serializer for your responses and you’re done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [serializer-method-field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to get value out of dictionary.

Below is the code to get color according to the sample which you provided.

```
class ApplicationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
    color = = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_color(self, obj):
        attribute_array = obj['attributeCollection']['attributeArray']
        color_attr = [attr for attr in attribute_array if attr['name'] == 'color']
        if color_attr:
            return color_attr[0]['value']

        return []
```

You can also use a [generator-expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to find the color_attribute from the array.

```
color_attr = next((attr for attr in attribute_array if attr["name"] == "color"), None)
return color_attr['value] if color_attr else []
```