# Serializer is_valid and no errors, but validated_data is empty (third party API and DRF)

Tags: python, json, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Making deserialization of data, getting from third party API. serializer is_valid but validated_data is an empty Dict

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CountrySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    countryId = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    countryName = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_countryId(self, data):
        return data["id"]

    def get_countryName(self, data):
        return data["code"]
```

```
from serializers import CountrySerializer


response = requests.get(url)
jsonResponse = response.json()
data = jsonResponse[0]
serializer = CountrySerializer(data=data)
in:
print(serializer.is_valid())
print(serializer.errors)
print(serializer.validated_data)
out: 
True 
{} 
OrderedDict()
```

So, i dont receive any errors after is_valid() but validated_data returns empty OrderedDict

When i'm checking the keys of dict in my Responce i get data needed:
in: print (data['id'], data['code'])
out: 9 DZ

Comment: How the data you receive looks like? What is the structure?

Comment: Its a list of dictionaries with nested dictionaries. Now i took just the first item of List - one dictionary: data = jsonResponse[0]. Later i would take the list and put many=true.

[
  {
    "id": "9",
    "code": "DZ",
    "name": [
      {
        "EN": [
          {
            "isVariation": "0",
            "name": "Algeria"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ID": [
          {
            "isVariation": "0",
            "name": "Aljazair"
          }
        ]
      },

Answer (score 0):

`SerializerMethodField` is read-only - you cannot validate incoming data with it, you need to use `CharField` instead:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class CountrySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    countryId = serializers.CharField()
    countryName = serializers.CharField()
```

Comment: i need SerializerMethodFIled beacuse other fields will be from nested dictionaries with a big depth, i will not reach without method.
And i saw examples when SerializerMethodField was used, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59490952/drf-serializer-manipulating-with-third-party-app-over-rest-api